# Javascript file organization and design

Tags: javascript

Really getting into web development and in particular JS so I was wondering what were the best practices in terms of JS file organization and delegation of responsibilities. I ask this because it would make sense to me to have this kind of structure:

- MAIN PAGE (PHP) (Includes a reference to a central JS file)
- MAIN Javascript File (Includes a reference to one file containing only error codes in a namespace or a class of B)

While this makes sense to me, I am wondering if I am wrong in my view considering the fact that you can't naturally include a JS file into another unless you do a couple tricks (no, not talking about jQuery). Tricks may mean that this isn't done simply because it doesn't fit with the best of practices for a language but it's not always the case in terms of cross-domain issues. So before I go too deep into sloppy design, I was just curious how you guys divided up the responsibilities or just slopped everything together into one file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to handle multiple JavaScript files is to design them like modules. One main JavaScript file should act as a sort of bootloader which kicks off things by setting up your "namespace" (quoted since JavaScript doesn't have classes). Example:

```
var myNamespace = {};
```

In each of your modules, you extend the "namespace". This has two benefits:

- Minimizes globals. In this case, you will have a single global.
- Easy to mix and match (and reuse) modules, if designed correctly.

Also see this for implementation details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3722845/221061

Comment: Thanks. In your case though, I assume that all the code is in one file, you are just cleaning it up by placing each in its own module correct?

Comment: You could do it that way, but that kind of defeats the purpose of modules. I would recommend putting each one in its own file so you can reuse them later (the mix-and-match part).

Answer (score 2):

I would split the classes up into modular JS files, matching your domain.  Use YUI compressor or other tools to compress JS files and minify them.

Answer (score 0):

One large JS file is really not that "bad" compared to using multiple JS files.

You can compress it on the server if your worried about band width, look into [gzip](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+compression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&expIds=17259,17315,23628,23670,23945,25041,25646,26761,26849,27520,27613,27889&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=gzip&cp=2&qe=Z3pp&qesig=W8uf8q1EXHMnRgLeLAugWg&pkc=AFgZ2tmT0wbYOMexJcbGFTn3DdkRbV5l-BfAzATL2Va15vuExwBej-OnF9zstB0lZqnzd900IHzhenb0QuasU3tvoPr3dwH17g&pf=p&sclient=psy&client=firefox-a&hs=BEt&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=gzi&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9bef8cda26d1a6ec) or deflate.

Comment: Oh it's not at all about space. Rather, about keeping everything neat and logical.