# How do I split up long JS code into seperate files as an object?

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have a file.js with a lot of functions and code, which I want to seperate into different files.

What would be a best-practice structure to do this? And I think that I'm talking about creating an object. But I'm not sure..

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4576581/221061

Comment: Why do you want to separate the file? Also, it's likely that such a big file contains inconsistent indentions. Copy-paste the contents at http://jsbeautifier.com/, to nicely format the code.

Comment: I am building an game engine and it's single file but the its exceeded the 2000 lines of code, and I want to clean it up a bit / seperate code to make it easier to edit / upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have a simple method of including other JavaScript files.  Generally I create several files and include them individually for testing.  For production I use ant to concatenate the files and apply something like the [closure-compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) and/or [yui compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) on the output.  Something like [this](https://jquery-ux-forms.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/build.xml) may serve as a good starting point.