# How to call a javascript constructor from an external file

Tags: javascript

I have a file (a.js) where is defined a constructor like this:

```
var Gauge = function( config) {
    Gauge.Collection.push( this);

    /**
     *  Default gauge configuration
     *  @struct
     */
    this.config = {
        renderTo         : null,
```

and also several functions.
I would like to create that object from an other file and then call  functions in it.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Just `new Gauge()`? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
myGauge = new Gauge();
```

If this doesn't match to your pattern, take a look at differnent **Javascript OOP patterns**, e.q. in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722820/examples-of-practical-javascript-object-oriented-design-patterns).

If my answer doesn't help, please post more code, e.q. on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that all you need to do is to make sure that `a.js`  is loaded before the file that you will be using to instantiate `Gauge`.