# Adding Properties to existing Javascript Objects from Object Constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor

When creating an object constructor in Javascript, I understand that it's necessary to prepend property names with the 'this' keyword.

```
function funcConstruct(first,last,age) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.age = age;
        this.fullNameAge = function() {
            return this.lastName + ', ' + this.firstName + ', ' + this.age
        };
};


var johnDoe = new funcConstruct('John', 'Doe', 52);
console.log(johnDoe.fullNameAge()); 
Doe, John, 52
```

If you wish to add additional properties to the object later, do you need to use the 'this' keyword, and if so, where does it go in the syntax?

Comment: `johnDoe.foo = 'bar';`. Also, while comma is not syntactically invalid, it is not good practice to end statements with it. Use a semicolon instead.

Comment: Whether you need to use `this` depends on what exactly you mean by "later" and how that code will be called.

Comment: Thanks Robert -- I swapped in semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional properties after the fact:

```
function funcConstruct(first,last,age) {
    this.firstName = first,
    this.lastName = last,
    this.age = age,
    this.fullNameAge = function() {
        return this.lastName + ', ' + this.firstName + ', ' + this.age
    }
};


var johnDoe = new funcConstruct('John', 'Doe', 52);
johnDoe.foo = "bar";
```

You are using the function constructor pattern, but note that there are other javascript object encapsulation patterns you can use depending on your use case some are better than others. In my opinion, I would use the function constructor pattern only if I was using pre ES6, if using >=ES6 (ES2015) I would use a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), and only if I needed a bunch of instances of the object. Otherwise, I would rather use the [revealing module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) if only a single instance of the object is required. Use fun

No use re-inventing the wheel, the accepted answer and some other highly voted answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722820/examples-of-practical-javascript-object-oriented-design-patterns) give a good summary. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImwrezYhw4w) explains some of the confusion around using `this` in javascript and provides an opinion that it is probably best to avoid `this` where possible.

Comment: Should note there are other ways to do it as well such as setter in constructor

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I'm new to OOP.  I understand there are other patterns for creating objects, and good reasons for avoiding this one, but I just wanted to make sure I understood how it worked on its most basic level.