# Singleton Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

1. What is the use of Singleton class?
2. Can anyone give me a scenario where
   Singleton class be applied?`{ If i
   am developing an Mobile App using
   JavaScript, what could be my
   Singleton Class here }`
3. Any examples on how to create
   Singleton Class in JavaScript.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: If you want to have a singleton, just create an object.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes.

Comment: @delnan functions are first class objects in Javascript. There isn't a actual implementation but Yes Javascript is OOP'ed if you ask me

Comment: @Deeptechtons "OOP'ed" does not mean it needs classes

Comment: @Deeptechtons: JS is most certainly object-oriented. But it doesn't implement objects as instances of classes, it has just objects and objects inherit from other objects. Talking of classes in JS is not just a factual error, it shows a confusion about the basics of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A class implements the Singleton pattern when it is desired that there should only be one instance of that class extant at any given time.
2. The example that I'm most familiar with is if you are, for example, creating a game and you only want one player-controlled entity to exist at a time; the player entity would use the Singleton pattern.
3. Actually using Singletons in Javascript is kind of wonky, but Dynamic's link above makes sense.

Comment: Singletons in JavaScript do not make sense. Since js only has objects. You don't create a singleton class, you just make a single object. The pattern is completely unapplicable to JS because your thinking in terms of classical OOP land.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72862943/8168578 here i share modern Javascript class with singelton pattern

Answer (score 0):

Its useful when you want to share an object across classes.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes.