# Create a single object

Tags: javascript, singleton, new-operator, instance

I want to create a single object. Does the below code make sense?

```
singleObj = new function () {
    // act as a constructor.
};
```

Am I hurting any good practice?

I need a constructor. A simple object literal would not be useful here.

Comment: maybe duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript

Comment: Why do you think you need a constructor *without* a custom prototype?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  The OP is invoking the `new` operator on an anonymous function.  I don't think I've ever seen that before and I've been writing JavaScript for at least 13 years.  It _is_ legal JavaScript, however....

Comment: *Why* wouldn't an object literal be useful there?  It seems like a text-book case to *moi*.

Comment: @Malvolio, because a literal wouldn't allow private scope?

Comment: Because I need a constructor Malvolio. Thank you.

Comment: @katspaugh -- if that's the case, he needs the [module](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) pattern, not to screw around with the `new` operator.

Comment: Ray Toal, so, what do you think? Is it a bad idea? Thanks.

Comment: @thom -- I know your response feels explanatory to you, but from the outside it is just circular.  *Why* do you need a constructor, especially for a singleton?

Comment: It might be convenient not to return any object explicitly.

Comment: I want to register some events in constructor. Thank you Malvolio.

Comment: @thom: You ought to stop repeating that. Stating that you "need" the thing that you've decided is going to be your implementation does not help us to understand _why_ you've decided that. "Why do you need a constructor?" "Because I need a constructor"

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a single object, in that you are never going to make one again, an object literal works perfectly here.

```
var x = { };
```

Will give you an object.
In order for

```
var F = function() {
};
```

to give you an object you will need to invoke `F`

```
var x = new F();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try someting like:

```
var objCreate = function() {
    var obj = {};
    // do constructor logic
    return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new object and then populate it. You don't need a contrustor to do this.

```
var singleObject = {};
singleObject.value1 = "whatever";
```

If you really want to use a function, then you need to actually call it.

```
var singleObj = new (function () {
    // act as a constructor.
})();
```

We can use a self executing function by creating a anonymous function `function(){}`, and immediately calling it with an empty argument set.

Comment: And it's not self-executing, unless it's a function cutting it's own head.

Comment: When `new` "calls" the function directly you can't pass in arguments.  The form I suggested will allow it. If you don't need to parametrize your constructor then there no point in calling either call forms.

Comment: Self-executing functions are commonly used to control name space pollution by creating new namespaces (closure). In essence they are used to create a set of variables that disappear at the end of a function. (ie they commit suicide.)

Comment: Local variables commit suicide upon any function's returning, so it's not a valid explanation for the term "self-executing".

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

```
//Used to create an object
personObj=new Object();
personObj.firstname="John";
personObj.lastname="Doe";
personObj.age=50;
personObj.eyecolor="blue";

//Used as a constructor for the object
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;
}
//how to declare objects via constructor template
var myFather=new person("John","Doe",50,"blue");
var myMother=new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");
```