# constructors inside a namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have read that creating a namespace for JavaScript projects helps to reduce conflicts with other libraries. I have some code with a lot of different types of objects for which I have defined constructor functions. Is it good practice to put these inside the namespace as well?

For example:

```
var shapes = {
    Rectangle: function(w, h) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }
};
```

which can be called via:

```
var square = new shapes.Rectangle(10,10);
```

Comment: Your constructor, which is a function, becomes a *function expression* instead of a *function declaration* if you assign it to an object property in a "namespace" instead of simply writing `function Rectangle(w, h) {}`. This has has slight differences: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions Other than that, it doesn't pollute the global namespace, which is a good thing, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This namespacing is called the "[Singleton pattern](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-design-patterns-pt1-singleton-composite-facade.html)" and it's one of the main patterns reccomended by the famous "[Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)" design patterns book.

From the great (and free) book [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript):

> Classically, the Singleton pattern can be implemented by creating a
>   class with a method that creates a new instance of the class if one
>   doesn't exist. In the event of an instance already existing, it simply
>   returns a reference to that object.The Singleton pattern is thus known
>   because it restricts instantiation of a class to a single object.
>
> In JavaScript, singletons serve as a namespace provider which isolate
>   implementation code from the global namespace so as to provide a
>   single point of access for functions.
>
> They can take on a number of different forms, but in its most basic, a
>   Singleton could be implemented as an object literal grouped together
>   with its related functions and properties...

So yes, it's a well used concept in many programming languages and a great for preventing global namespace object collisions in JavaScript.

See also: [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Also thanks for the links. I just hadn't seen any examples of anyone calling `new` for a function in a namespace and wondered if there was a reason for that.

Comment: No reason that I can think of. The new function is JavaScript's prototypical inheritance, which is often used in practice as more of a class-like inheritance. Most examples you'll see define just a single "class," but if you're trying to organize a bunch of them the singleton pattern is equally if not more useful.

Comment: @joe of course, it's not considered singleton pattern if the object literal contains constructors ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This is generally a good idea; additionally, if your objects require a set of shared functions that should not be exposed you can wrap them all inside a closure, like a module:

```
var shapes = (function() {
  // private variables
  var foo = 0;

  // private function
  function get_area(w, h)
  {
    return w * h;
  }

  return {
    Rectangle: function(w, h) {
      this.width = w;
      this.height = h;
      // call private function to determine area (contrived example)
      this.area = get_area(w, h);
    }
  }
}());

var s = new shapes.Rectangle(100, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You should pollute the global namespace the least possible

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's a good idea, because you avoid the hassle and confusing caused by polluting the global namespace. Although I personally would change `shapes` to `shape`, so you could then have a `shape.Rectangle`, which makes a little more sense to me (after all, a Rectangle is only one object).

Answer (score 1):

Besides not polluting the namespace, it also enables you to do type family checking:

```
function doSomethingTo(shape) {
  var shapeName, validArg;

  for (shapeName in shapes) {
    validArg = validArg || shape instanceof shapes[shapeName];
  }

  if ( !validArg ) throw "Argument is not a shape.";
}
```