# How/why does this JS singleton pattern work?

Tags: javascript, constructor, singleton, this

I came across this rather interesting way to create a JavaScript singleton that can be instantiated with the `new` keyword, like `var x = new SingletonClass()`. I have a pretty good grasp of variable scope and closures, etc., but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly why this block of code works the way it does.

```
// EDIT: DO NOT USE this code; see the answers below
function SingletonClass() {
  this.instance = null;
  var things = [];

  function getInstance() {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = {
        add: function(thing) {
          things.push(thing);
        },
        list: function() {
          console.log(things.toString());
        }
      };
    }
    return this.instance;
  }

  return getInstance();
}

var obj1 = new SingletonClass();
obj1.add("apple");
obj1.list();  //"apple"

var obj2 = new SingletonClass();
obj2.add("banana");
obj1.list();  //"apple,banana"
obj2.list();  //"apple,banana"

obj1.add("carrot");
obj1.list();  //"apple,banana,carrot"
obj2.list();  //"apple,banana,carrot"
```

My intuition says that each time a new `SingletonClass` is instantiated, `this` refers to that fresh new object -- but then since a totally separate object is returned by the constructor, I would figure `this` would just get discarded. But it hangs around. How? Why?

There's some tiny little detail going on here that I'm missing. Can anybody shine some light on it?

**EDIT:** Turns out this code is bad. The reason why it "magically" seems to hold a reference to the instance is because it's actually silently storing it in the global object. It's bad practice at best, and undoubtedly bug-prone.

Comment: Where did you find this? It looks broken to me. The "getInstance" function is invoked without an explicit receiver, so `this` will be the global object (`window` in a browser).

Comment: Note that if called in strict mode, `this` in `getInstance` will be undefined, throwing a reference error (or similar) attempting to evaluate `this.instance`.

Comment: You're right @Pointy, I realize now that it **is** (conceptually) broken. The thought had never crossed my mind that `this` could refer to the global object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confused by the `this` inside the function `getInstance`, that `this` is the global object `window`, so you are creating an object and assigned to the window object, and next time you call the constructor, you are checking whether `window.instance` is existing.

The code `this.instance = null;` is meanless, just confusing you. Remove it won't change anything.

The below is from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

> When the code `new foo(...)` is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from foo.prototype.
> 2. The constructor function foo is called with the specified arguments
>      and this bound to the newly created object. new foo is equivalent to
>      `new foo()`, i.e. if no argument list is specified, foo is called
>      without arguments.
> 3. **The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result
>      of the whole new expression.** If the constructor function doesn't
>      explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>      instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>      choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>      process.)

Note the step3, when you have return statement in constructor, the returned result will be the result of the new expression.

Comment: Yup, I see that now. I took it for granted that `this` would always mean, well, `this` and I never even thought to check the global object. I'll amend the code with a big DO NOT USE comment in case somebody gets the bright idea to copy it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

When the constructor calls `getInstance()`, the `this` pointer inside `getInstance()` is set to `window` so `this.instance` inside of it is a global variable `window.instance`.

This code just uses a global variable `window.instance` to keep track of the one instance and could be made a LOT simpler than it is.

A much cleaner way to implement this would be this.  The one global instance is stored as a property of the function itself rather than in a top-level global variable.

```
    function SingletonClass() {
        var things = [];

        // if there is a previous instance, return it
        if (SingletonClass.inst) {
            return SingletonClass.inst;
        }
        // if not called with 'new', force it
        if (!this instanceof SingletonClass) {
            return new SingletonClass();
        }

        // remember the first created instance
        SingletonClass.inst = this;

        // add methods that can see our private `things` variable
        this.add = function(thing) {
           things.push(thing);
        }

        this.list = function() {
            console.log(things.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Added a much cleaner implementation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's using `window` - `getInstance`'s `this` is not the same as `SingletonClass`'s this:

```
function Singleton() {
    console.log("This is:", this);
    this.instance = null;

    function _get() {
        console.log("_get's this is:", this);
        if (!this.instance) {
           console.log("Instance is null");
           this.instance = { test: 1 };
        }
        return this.instance;
    }

    return _get();
}

var x = new Singleton();

// Output is:
This is: 
Singleton
_get's this is: 
Window
Instance is null
```

A better way to implement the Singleton pattern in JavaScript might be:

```
function Singleton() {

    // Handle not being called with `new`
    if (!this instanceof Singleton) {
        return new Singleton();
    }

    var instantiating = !!Singleton.instance,
        things = [];

    Singleton.instance = instantiating ? this : Singleton.instance;

    if (instantiating) {
        this.list = function() {
            console.log(things.toString());
        }

        this.add = function(item) {
            things.push(item);
        }
    }

    return Singleton.instance;
}
```

This still suffers from limitations. For example, if someone replaces `Singleton.instance` with another object then tests between different instances of `Singleton` may break - e.g.:

```
var x = new Singleton();
// Har, har, we be breaking things!
Singleton.instance = {"not": "the", "same": "at", "all": true};
var y = new Singleton();

console.log(x === y); // false
```

Comment: It's a shame I can only accept one answer, because I like this answer too (especially the replacement code). The thing that originally drew me to the code I posted was the fact that it purported to do this without adding a property to the class -- but it turns out it was snake oil, storing it in `window` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` in the `getInstance` function indicates a `Window` object. In the `SingletonClass` function, it indicates a `SingletonClass` object.

With lexical scope, the `add` and `list` functions always refer to the same `things` array.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good link on singletons:

[Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

Here is an example that pertains to what you are doing above:

```
var myInstance = {
    method1: function () {
        return "Apple";
    },
    method2: function () {
        return "Orange";
    },
    banana: "Banana"
};

myInstance.grape = "Grape";

console.log(myInstance.method1(), myInstance.method2(), myInstance.banana, myInstance.grape);
```

Here is working link:

http://www.quirkscode.com/flat/forumPosts/singleton/singleton.html