# Good Singleton Pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I use the following Singleton pattern in JavaScript:

```
  var exampleClass =(function(){ 
                        //private
                        var a ="test"; 
                        function PrivateMethod()
                        {
                            return a;
                        }
                        //public
                        return{  
                            Test: function() { 
                                   alert(PrivateMethod()); 
                                  } 
                        }
                      })();
```

As I read through StackOverflow I see a lot of other implementations of Singleton and I start to doubt if I couldn't make mine better.
I hope someone can tell me what's right or wrong about doing it this way.

Comment: What is the actual use this Pattern in Javascript?

Comment: Mostly for separating all functions and variables from other functions, but I also have for instance a popuphelper which uses its private variables to keep the last state. I want all developers to use that class and not instantiate a new class. So only one "instance" may exist in the application. To keep some, for example ,coordinates of the popup as global variables doesn't feel right. I think it's much better to use Popup.Open() and handle all the logic and variables inside that class.

Comment: Some good examples:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript

Comment: I know the examples, but i know a lot of people use my implementation and i just want to know why and if i should switch to another pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want to achieve as the different implementations will have different benefits and limitations.

The simplest implementation is just an object literal:

```
var singleton = {
    property: "foo",
    method: function() {
        alert('bar');
    }
}
```

The implementation you mention in the question allows public and private methods by encapsulating the methods in a closure and returning what should be exposed.

Here is an alternative which similarly would allow public and private methods and is more extensible:

```
function MySingletonClass() {

  if ( arguments.callee._singletonInstance )
    return arguments.callee._singletonInstance;
  arguments.callee._singletonInstance = this;

  this.Foo = function() {
    // ...
  }
}

var a = new MySingletonClass()
var b = MySingletonClass()
Print( a === b ); // prints: true
```

Comment: You can call the constructor multiple times allowing for prototypal inheritance

Answer (score 1):

This is mine.

Differences are:

- all functions declared at top
- all functions are private by default
- all functions have access to other functions
- public functions are mapped at bottom

Improvements are:

- if you want to move a function from private to public or viceversa, you don't have to move code, only change mapping at bottom of code
- all functions have access to both private and public functions (because all functions are private by default)

  ```
  var exampleClass =(function(){ 

                  //private
                  var a ="test"; 

                  //declare here all functions 
                  //(both for pass jslint validation and is good to have a list
                  //of all available functions, in case of classes with a lot of code

                  var PrivateMethod,
                  Test1,
                  Test2;

                  PrivateMethod = function()
                  {
                      return a;
                  };

                  Test1 = function()
                  {
                      return PrivateMethod();
                  };

                  Test2 = function()
                  {
                      return Test1();
                  };


                  //public
                  //Expose function you want to have pubblic
                  return{  
                      Test1: Test1,
                      Test2: Test2 
                  }
                })();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this pattern:

```
var SingletonConstructor;
(function() {
    var instance;
    SingletonConstructor = function() {

        if (typeof instance !== 'undefined')
           return instance;

        var a = "a";

        function PrivateMethod() {
            return a;
        }

        return instance = this;
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Google Closure do it:

http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js#427

Answer (score 0):

I love the following pattern:

```
function MyClass(){
    if(MyClass.instance){
        return MyClass.instance;
    }
    MyClass.instance = this;

    //constructor code goes here
}

var a = new MyClass();
var b = new MyClass();

console.log(a == b); //true
```