# Replace function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Can this be rewritten in some better form?

```
function F() { return F.f(); } //wrapping :(
F.f = function() { /* code1 */ }
F.g = function() { /* code2 */ }

F.f = some_other_function
F.g() //this still works :D
```

I'm never going to create any instances of F. I just use it as a sort of a namespace.
I've tried doing the following but F.g doesn't get preserved (I can understand why, but I'd like a nice workaround to be able to change the code and behaviour of F but not the bindings like F.g):

```
function F() { /* code1 */ } //no wrapping :D, no need for F.f
F.g = function() { /* code2 */ }

F = some_other_function
F.g() //this points to nowhere now :(
```

EDIT:
I want to not have to use F.f anymore as a wrapper for `code1`.

EDIT2: The first piece of code is valid JS and has the behaviour that I want. The problem is that I don't like that I have to use F.f at all. I would like to do it like in the second but of code and still have F.g working.
At some point at runtime I would like to change `code1` and leave everything else untouched.

Comment: [Singleton pattern in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

Comment: You could do `Function.prototype.g = function() { /* code2 */ };` but then all functions would have g's functionality, even g itself. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here at all. Could you provide some usecase for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
var F = {
    f: function() {
        /* code1 */
    },
    g: function() {
        /* code2 */
    }
 };

F.f = function() { /* redefine F.f() */ }
// or
delete F.f;

F.g(); // still works
```

-

### Updated answer from question clarification

This is a way to accomplish this, although this whole idea is a bit off.  Not sure why you would want this pattern.

```
function generate() {
    var f = function() {
        /* code1 */
    };

    var ret_val = function() {
        f();
    };

    ret_val.g = function() {
        /* code2 */
    };

    ret_val.setBehaviour = function(new_func) {
        f = new_func;
    };
}

F = generate();

F(); /* code1 */
F.g(); /* code2 */

F.setBehaviour(function() { /* redefine F() */ });
F.g(); /* code2 still works */

F(); /* new behaviour */
```

Comment: Sorry, but I want to get rid of f entirely and leave g alone

Comment: @madflame991 you can always set `F.f` to `null` if you want.

Comment: I think the OP wants `F.g` to exist regardless of what `F` is. `F.f` is beside the point, *I think*.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var F = (function() {
  console.log("Something..");

  return function() {
    function g() {
      console.log("I'm G!");
    }
  };
})();

F.g();
```

Now you can initialize something (looks like that's you want with F.f) and preserve F.g

Comment: This will log "Something.." as soon as the file is executed and then there is no way to call g...??? not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.