# How to use a private function from outside of the class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, singleton

I try to convert my old function into singleton class structers and patterns. 
Oldly i have some function that create XHR calls and build some elements with returned html data.

I wonder how could i use it in sigleton pattern, here is my code structure beginning

```
var evraklarPanel = {}
evraklarPanel.isTipleri = {
    yeniEvraktipi: function () {
        $.post("evraklarPanel_action.asp", {istipi: 'yeniEvrakTipiGrupAdi'}, function (data) {
            if () {} else {}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is your **14th** question, and you still aren't formatting your code? When you were posting your question, there was this handy **How to Format** box to the right. There was also a preview area underneath where you could see the result before posting. And of course, you were shown the result once you posted.

Comment: Sorry for misformatting.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, but the question doesn't really make sense. What is the "private" function that you try to access? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: At the old functions, i was calling the function which handle onclick event of anchor and make a XHR call, than build an element with returned html from server. From now i want to use singleton pattern and classes. evraklarPanel is as same as the page using this js. Outside of the namespace, how can i use private functions that belongs this namespace.

Comment: Note that the singleton object is not a class, and it doesn't have private functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've really only defined one function there (other than the ajax callback), I'm guessing you want to know how to call `yeniEvraktipi`. You do that like this:

```
evraklarPanel.isTipleri.yeniEvraktipi();
```

Comment: Thank you T.J. Crowder. Because of my language problem i couldn't explain what i exactly want. The text editor that i am using, didn't show .yeniEvraktipi() completing tip. Thank you very much. It is very funny to OOPlike coding.

Comment: @caglaror: Glad that helped! It's just calling a method (`yeniEvraktipi`) on a field (`isTipleri`) of an object (`evraklarPanel`). You could find yourself doing the same thing in Java or C#.

Comment: Hmmm, now, when i call the method, no error occurs. But simply added **alert('hello world');** inside the method for control, not worked.

Comment: @caglaror: Works just fine: http://jsbin.com/opetuz/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/opetuz/1/edit)