# javascript calling the function from prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am learning javascript. When I call pictureArrayAdd method I receive error Picture.pictureArrayAdd is not a function. Why?

```
window.onload = init;
//window.picture = new Array();

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = addPicture;
}

function Picture() {};

Picture.prototype = {
    pictureArray: [],
    pictureArrayAdd: function(newImage) {
        this.pictureArray.push(newImage);
        return this

    }
}


var addPicture = function() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById ("pictureName");
    var newPicture = textInput.value;
    Picture.pictureArrayAdd(newPicture);

}
```

Comment: You'll want to create an instance: `var picture = new Picture();` `picture.pictureArrayAdd(...)`. Otherwise, you don't need a constructor if you just want a [singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript): `var Picture = {...};`

Comment: Try new Picture.pictureArrayAdd(newPicture)
Protoype stuff are accesible from function instances using 'new'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize an instace of your object:

```
var addPicture = function() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById ("pictureName");
    var newPicture = textInput.value;
    var pic = new Picture();
    pic.pictureArrayAdd(newPicture);
}
```

Besides - just a tip -, you can use a optional parameter on your constructor, like this:

```
function Picture(newImage) {
    if (newImage != undefined) {
        this.pictureArrayAdd(newImage);
    }
};
```

So you have a shortcut to your `pictureArrayAdd` function:

```
var pic = new Picture("picture1.png");
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Bp8t/).