# Is it possible to use a constructor in a Javascript object literal to avoid instantiation?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have an object that needs certain properties to be set by execution instead of assignment.  Is it possible to do this using a literal object notation?

I would like to be able to access the object's properties using this:

`myObject.propertyName`

...rather than this:

```
objInstance = new myObject();
objInstance.propertyName;
```

**EDIT:** to clarify, based on *Bergi's* answer, this is what I'm aiming to do:

```
var myObj = {
    myInfo: (function() { return myObj.getInfo('myInfo'); })(),
    getInfo: function() { 
      /* lots of execution here that would be redundant if done within myInfo */
    }
}

// access the calculated property value
myObj.myInfo;
```

But this gives me the error `myObj is not defined`

Comment: What is "instantialialization"?

Comment: If you don't get useful answers it might be that I'm not the only one who didn't understand your question. In that case a little more code might be a valuable addition.

Comment: @Bergi: sorry, I thought this was less obscure term than it actually is :)

http://dictionary.sensagent.com/instantialization/en-en/

Comment: @Recovering: Ah, since there are neither templates nor static typing in JS I've never heard of it (and it doesn't really apply). I've first thought of a portmanteau from *instantiation* (creating an object) and *initialisation* (executing the constructor)

Comment: "instantiation" ... that's the word I was looking for.  I guess it overcomplexitized it :)

Comment: no, literals can only create native constructor instances. you can use Object.defineProperty to do anything you want upon execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Bergi** to finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations), here is a final example what I wanted to do:

```
myObj = {
   init: function() {
        this.oneProperty = anyCodeIWant...
        this.anotherProperty = moreCodeIWant...
        // and so on
        return this;
   }
}.init();

myObj.oneProperty;
myObj.anotherProperty;
// and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want is an [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), which you can put inside an object literal:

```
var myObject = {
    propertyName: (function() {
        var it = 5*3; // compute something and
        return it;
    }()),
    anotherFunction: function() {…}
};

myObject.propertyName // 15
```

Maybe you also want to use the module pattern. Have a look at [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1479319/1048572).

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but how do I call another function defined as a property of the object?  It results in an error `[object] is not defined`

Comment: No idea what your code looks like. But you just would put the functions on the object literal as usually.

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic: Or do you mean calling them from the IEFE? That won't work, as the object doesn't yet exist when it is executed. Use the module pattern then. Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations

Comment: @Bergi: That's it!  The module pattern.  Thanks!