# Javascript singleton

Tags: javascript, singleton

Can someone explain

1. why `a` and `b` refer to the same object here?

What if I want to create two different instances of Singleton
    object(I know it is against the design pattern, but just for
    learning purpose), what should I modify?

```
function MySingletonClass() {
    if ( arguments.callee._singletonInstance )
        return arguments.callee._singletonInstance;
    arguments.callee._singletonInstance = this;

    this.Foo = function() {
        // ...
    }
}

var a = new MySingletonClass()
var b = MySingletonClass()
Print( a === b ); // prints: true
```

Comment: That's some weird syntax you have here. I don't know what `new function...` does but it definitely does not return a function (it returns an object at least under Chrome). So `new Singleton()` should throw an exception. On the other hand if `new function` is just a mistake (and it is simply `function`) then these instances won't be the same.

Comment: It's not quite right. Change the order of `var a = ...` and `var b = ...` and it will print false.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript for some working implementations

Comment: I was following the guide on google, https://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips#Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 1):

No idea  what are you trying to achieve here, but proper singleton implementation should not allow creating `new Singleton()` by calling its constructor

Following code implements the singleton in correct way IMHO:
`

```
var Singleton =  new function () 
{
    var instance = this;
    this.getInstance = function()
    {
        if(!instance)
            instance = new Singleton();

        return instance;
    }
}

//var instance1 = new Singleton();// should not work
//var instance2 = new Singleton();
//alert( instance2 == instance1 ); 
alert (Singleton.getInstance() == Singleton.getInstance()) // returns true
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is slightly tricky: `MySingletonClass` acts as a function, an object, and a constructor in different contexts. Also the constructor sometimes returns a different object, instead of modifying `this` as usual.

The singleton object is stored as a property of the function `MySingletonClass` i.e. `MySingletonClass._singletonInstance`.

`MySingletonClass` is called as either a function (`MySingletonClass()`) or a constructor (`new MySingletonClass()`). When it is called, the object may or may not already exist. Let's look at these cases:

- **Constructor - Object exists**

  `arguments.callee` is just the function so you could use `MySingletonClass._singletonInstance` instead. The first line checks if the object exists, and then the second returns it. Because an object is returned from the constructor, the result of the new expression is that object.
- **Constructor - Object does not exist**

  The singleton object is set to `this`, the object that is currently being constructed, and then `this` is initialized by adding some functions (`Foo` etc). The call to the constructor then evaluates to `this`. The object now exists so it won't be initialized again.
- **Function - Object exists**

  `arguments.callee` is still the function so the object is returned as before.
- **Function - Object does not exist**

  Here, `this` is the global object, so the `_singletonInstance` variable and the `Foo` functions are added to the global object. The function doesn't return anything so `b` becomes `undefined`. This is not the behavior you want.

In the first three cases, the object `MySingletonClass._singletonInstance` is initialized if it doesn't exist, and then the calling expression evaluates to that instance.

As for multiple instances, it wouldn't make much sense to create multiple instances of a singleton. How would you specify which instance to get? If you want multiple instances, just remove the `arguments.callee` code at the beginning and you have a non-singleton constructor.