# Javascript literal object and singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, ooad

Isn't the literal object instantiation in javascript a singleton?

Of course there is no "self" instantiation if the object is not found, but there is only one "copy" of the object kept around.

what are your thoughts?

Comment: Related: [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the article:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript

*Singletons differ from static classes (or objects) as we can delay their initialization, generally because they require some information that may not be available during initialization time. They don't provide a way for code that is unaware of a previous reference to them to easily retrieve them. This is because it is neither the object or "class" that's returned by a Singleton, it's a structure. Think of how closured variables aren't actually closures - the function scope that provides the closure is the closure.*

Comment: This is an 8 year old thread, but I found it useful! Thank you :). That quote makes so much sense especially it's the "structure" that is returned.