# how do I call sibling functions in a singleton class?

Tags: javascript, object, singleton, siblings

In the following code, `.refresh` could call `.add`, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
My guess is because it is not defined at the time class is created, but if this is true, without replicating the code, is there a way to call a sibling public function from the same class?

```
var fileSelector = (function () {
    var self = this;
    function callback (data,status,xhr) {
        $("#File_Selector_Container").html(data);
        utils.setItem ("fileSelector", "TRUE");
    }
    return {
        refresh : function () {
            if (utils.getItem ("fileSelector") == "TRUE") {
                self.add();
            }
        },
        add : function () {
            $.get(script_name ,"AddFileSelector",callback,"html");
        },
        remove : function () {
            $("#File_Selector_Container").html("");
        }
    }
})();
```

I started this from: [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript) and I can't find it now, but another question where I got `self=this` from.

Comment: `this` (and hence `self`) simply refers to the global object (i.e. `window`). That's why you get the error, there is no global `add` function.  I recommend to read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn how `this` works.

Comment: this.add() did work, however,  looking at the 2nd suggestion.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` (and hence `self`) simply refers to the global object (i.e. `window`). That's why you get the error, there is no global `add` function.  I recommend to read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn how `this` works.

One solution is to keep a reference to the object you are returning and use that instead:

```
var fileSelector = (function () {
    function callback (data,status,xhr) {
        $("#File_Selector_Container").html(data);
        utils.setItem ("fileSelector", "TRUE");
    }
    var fileSelector = {
        refresh : function () {
            if (utils.getItem ("fileSelector") == "TRUE") {
                fileSelector.add();
            }
        },
        add : function () {
            $.get(script_name ,"AddFileSelector",callback,"html");
        },
        remove : function () {
            $("#File_Selector_Container").html("");
        }
    };

    return fileSelector;
})();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and I like this much better, it is so much easier to follow what is where, Thanks!!