# Javascript singleton scope issue

Tags: javascript, singleton

I have the following code:

```
var mySigleton = new function()
{
    this.count = 123;
    document.write("<div onclick='ShowCount();''>Click</div>");

    function ShowCount() {
        alert(this.count);    
    };
}();
```

I need to call the function ShowCount() from the onclick event of the div created by the document.write(). However, I'm getting an error that ShowCount is undefined.  Also, the ShowCount event has to access a value defined inside the singleton.

Comment: Inline event handlers run in global scope. You can use the locally defined function if you use the DOM API to create the element. However, even if you did that, `this` inside `ShowCount` won't refer to your singleton. Just make `count` a local variable and have `ShowCount` access it.

Comment: [Never ever use `new function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key-as-static) - it's *not* a singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `ShowCount()` accessible from outside the constructor function. You can do this by attaching the function to a `ShowCount` property of the returned instance. You then would need to call `mySingleton.ShowCount()`:

```js
var mySingleton = new function()
{
    this.count = 123;
    document.write("<div onclick='mySingleton.ShowCount();'>Click</div>");

    this.ShowCount = function() {
        alert(this.count);    
    };
}();
```

Remark: This is just to demonstrate how to fix your implementation, but as already pointed out in the comments above, it is **not** good style.

A better implementation would create the element and attach its event handlers using the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) while avoiding [`document.write()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice). Also, your singleton is actually none, so better rename it to something else to avoid confusion (or implement a [real singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)):

```js
function myClass() {
  this.count = 123;
  
  // Create <div> and attach onclick handler:
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 'Click';
  div.onclick = () => alert(this.count);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
};


let instance = new myClass();
```

Depending on your use-case, it might still be unusual to have a constructor function create DOM elements.

Comment: Why not fix the implementation with the better style?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I agree it's not good style. But it is existing code and I can't refactor at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is unclear...

By the way, there are **lots** of possible implementations of the Singleton pattern in JavaScript. Here is a possible one, with an IIFE:

```js
var showCount = (function () {
  var count = 123;
  document.body.innerHTML = '<div onclick="showCount();">Click</div>';
  
  return function () {
    alert(count);
  }
})();
```