# Jquery execute function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code:

```
$(Page).on('click', '*', function(e)
{
    myFunction();
}

function myFunction(){//do something...}
```

I would like the code in the function to be done only once, now when I click, for example, 5 times, the code from the function `myFunction()` will be executed 5 times. I don't want to change `on('click', '*', ...`

Comment: Use `one()` instead of `on()`.  It behaves the same, but it unbinds after the first time it executes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

Comment: a global var? myfunctionRunned = false; and when is executed inside myFunction() just ask if(myfunctionRunned)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `one` method.

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Simply change your `.on` to `.one`.

```
$(Page).one('click', '*', function(e) {
  myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
  // do something
}
```

[Here's the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for `one`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **[`$.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

```
$(Page).one('click', '*', function(e)
     myFunction();
});
```

Or, better:

```
$(Page).one('click', '*', myFunction);
```

Be careful with that event delegation who will bind the event click to the whole set of elements within the DOM tree of `Page`.

Comment: Uh, it doesn't bind to all of them, it just matches against all the children.  It's still just bound to whatever `Page` is.