# How can I type a method with 'this' inside object literal in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```js
const log = {
  counter: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
  },
  increment(entry: keyof typeof this.counter){
    this.counter[entry]++;
  }
};

function incrementLog(entry:keyof typeof log.counter){
    log.counter[entry]++;
}

incrementLog('a'); // ok
incrementLog('d'); // error, must be 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
log.increment('a'); // ok
log.increment('d'); // no error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA5jAvDA3gKBjUBXMKAUwCcAuDbHGAQwoEYAaKnAIwoCZnrcKBmbjAC+ggJZhgJIgFsihABRyoJAJ4UA1kRUgAZjCgqADkV36AFqIgA6fIVIBKLDygXrt4iQDaS1QF0A1P4A3FRCmEIhmDoEwFCi4DDikjJKADJIioSqZJraegbGpgiINiAEHo4s8Eil5aTeWSoBweGYmElSsoTpiPIA5DR99kEwAPSjMCDq7RKdaRl9ACZDI+MwpCQgJIww0njQMKxEMAN9MAA+J6xnl33AfZjFVh0pCqfDYxNTjzUvXVD9ZYfNZgEDrEibEiYIA)

I want to enforce the argument type of `increment` method to be `keyof typeof log.counter`, which is `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`. I can achieve it in the standalone function, but it doesn't work in the `increment` method: `'this' is not defined.`

I've also tried `log.counter` instead of `this.counter` on the method definition, but that creates a 'circular initializer' which also doesn't work as intended.

I hope not to manually type the `log` or manually type the `counter`, because when I make changes to the object, I hope to only make changes in one place.

Comment: Can you give this.counter a type and refer to that instead?

Comment: Yes but if I need to add an item, I'll need to make changes in two places.I want it to be automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `counter` before `log`. You cannot reference type in the middle of expression which defines the type. You can easily avoid duplicating definition/initialization.

```js
const counter = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
};
const log = {
  counter,
  increment(entry: keyof typeof counter){
    this.counter[entry]++;
  }
};

function incrementLog(entry:keyof typeof log.counter){
    log.counter[entry]++;
}

incrementLog('a'); // ok
incrementLog('d'); // error, must be 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
log.increment('a'); // ok
log.increment('d'); // error, must be 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Answer (score 2):

When writing object-oriented code in TypeScript, it's a lot easier to use class syntax than it is to force things to work with plain object literals:

```
class Log {
  counter = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  };

  increment(entry: keyof Log['counter']) {
    this.counter[entry]++;
  }
}

const log = new Log();

function incrementLog(entry:keyof Log['counter']) {
  log.counter[entry]++;
}

incrementLog('a'); // ok
incrementLog('d'); // error
log.increment('a'); // ok
log.increment('d'); // error
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I accepted Nenad's answer because it's closest to the original question, but your answer is also great!

Comment: @Quuxuu I agree, I hadn't thought of his approach when I posted this, and I like it too which is why I upvoted it. However, if you end up adding a lot of properties to `log`, this approach ends up being a little cleaner because it avoids cluttering the scope with a lot of temporary variables.

Comment: Inspired by the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript), I also found that if I remove counter completely from the object, and simply use the "temporary variable", it becomes "private states of a singleton" instead of "cluttering the scope".

Answer (score 0):

You should create a type or interface for `log`:

```
interface Log<T extends {[key: string]: number}> {
    counter: T;
    increment(element: keyof T): void;
}
```

Comment: In this way, whenever I need to add a new method, I'll need to make changes in two places? (the interface and the object)

Comment: Instead of an interface, you can also use a class.

Comment: btw I also don't want to type it as "string", because I want intellisense when calling the method

Comment: intellisense will recognize it, since your increment method will map the accepted values towards the keys that are present in the actual object.