# NodeJS: What is the best way to implement OAuth client logic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm currently implementind OpenID/OAuth authorization in my project and using [openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client) package for that.

In this package we initialize an openid client with the following code:

```
const { Issuer } = require('openid-client');
Issuer.discover('https://accounts.google.com') // => Promise
  .then(function (googleIssuer) {
    console.log('Discovered issuer %s %O', googleIssuer.issuer, googleIssuer.metadata);
  });
  
const client = new googleIssuer.Client({
  client_id: 'zELcpfANLqY7Oqas',
  client_secret: 'TQV5U29k1gHibH5bx1layBo0OSAvAbRT3UYW3EWrSYBB5swxjVfWUa1BS8lqzxG/0v9wruMcrGadany3',
  redirect_uris: ['http://localhost:3000/cb'],
  response_types: ['code'],
  // id_token_signed_response_alg (default "RS256")
  // token_endpoint_auth_method (default "client_secret_basic")
}); // => Client
```

How we can implement a singleton client logic?
To create a client only once and reuse it all over the application?

I've tried to create a separate class for that but not sure if it is correct:

```
import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';

export class OpenIdClient {
  

  async createOpenIdClient() {
    const issuer = await Issuer.discover(encodeURI(`http://localhost:3101/.well-knownendpoint`));

    const client = await new issuer.Client({
      client_id: 'clientId',
      client_secret: 'clientSecret'
    })

    return client;
  }
}
```

Comment: You may wish to redact your client_id and client_secret in the future. If this is just demo code then it's fine, but from a security standpoint, you'd consider your OAuth to be compromised at this point until you re-generate the secret.

Comment: @UberMario, thank you for the advice, I'll not use hardcoded string values on production, it's just for stackoverflow example :)

Answer (score 0):

You're close here, and using a class can be a solution, though I find classes to be less useful if all you're after is a singleton. Classes are great when you want to instance more than one time (or at least have the ability to).

I usually just use a plain variable or object for a singleton. No need to use anything more complicated here.

Note there are [other answers for how to create singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-a-singleton-in-javascript?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top), so this is just my own opinion on the best/simplest solution for your needs.

In a separate file (e.g. oauth-client.js):

```
// oauth-client.js
const { Issuer } = require('openid-client');

Issuer.discover('https://accounts.google.com')
  .then(function (googleIssuer) {
    console.log('Discovered issuer %s %O', googleIssuer.issuer, googleIssuer.metadata);
  });
  
const client = new googleIssuer.Client({
  client_id: 'redacted',
  client_secret: 'redacted',
  redirect_uris: ['http://localhost:3000/cb'],
  response_types: ['code'],
});

module.exports = client;
```

The first time it's loaded by a file, it'll instantiate. Any subsequent times it's loaded in the node.js app, it won't re-instantiate. It'll reuse the entity that's already in memory.

```
//other file, let's pretend in the same file path.
const oauthClient = require('./oauth-client');

...
```

If you're wanting to make sure for yourself, put a log line at the top of the singleton file. Then load the file from two different parts of your app. You'll see that it only logs it out once.

---

To answer the question in the comments below: Swap these lines for an object destructured approach, which makes it nice for if you want to export multiple things from the file:

```
...
module.exports = { oauthClient: client }
```

```
const { oauthClient } = require('./oauth-client');
...
```

Since we aren't exporting more than one thing (the client), the original answer is still fine.

Comment: thank you very much! is it possible to write it in ES6 CommonJS syntax?

Comment: It is in CommonJS syntax. Do you mean using the object destructured approach instead of single variable assignment on module.exports? Just trying to understand what you're asking