# Nodejs : Changes to Singleton object property values not persisting/reflecting in other JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, singleton

How do I persist changes to `values` inside a `Singleton` class object?

I set and get a class object `value` with a `setter` and `getter` method like:

```
wwjsInstances.setInstance("name1", client);
wwjsInstances.getInstance("name1")
```

My `wwjsInstances.js`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Singleton : wwjsInstances Class
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
class wwjsInstances {

    // Var > Initialize
    message;
    instances = {};

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Constructor
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    constructor() {
        this.message = 'I am an instance';
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Method
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    setInstance(clientId, clientSession) {

        try {

            this.instances[clientId] = clientSession;

        } catch (err) {

            throw new Error("[wwjsInstances] : Failed to Attach Session to Singleton", err);

        }

        return true;
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Method
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    getInstance( clientId ){

        return this.instances[clientId]

    }

}

module.exports = new wwjsInstances();
```

The `value` of the class object is another object ( non UI WhatsApp Web Client Object, used for all WhatsApp operations )

Inside my `/server.js` file,  I got this snippet:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Whatsapp Client
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

const wwjsServiceModule = require("./app/services/wwjsService");
const wwjsInstances = require('./app/services/wwjsInstances');

// Starts > Non-UI WhatsApp Web App
wwjsServiceModule.createSession("name1").then((client) => {

    // Add > Instance Object [ Non-UI WhatsApp Web App ] > To > Singleton > Object Array [ There can be multiple clients running concurrently ]
    wwjsInstances.setInstance("name1", client);
    
    // Log
    console.log('wwjsInstances.getInstance: ', wwjsInstances.getInstance("name1")); // works, sample log below:
    
    // <ref *1> Client
    // {
    //     _events: [Object
    // :
    //     null
    //     prototype
    // ]
    //     {
    //         authenticated: [Function(anonymous)],
    //             auth_failure
    //     :
    //         [Function(anonymous)],
    //             loading_screen
    //     :
    //         [Function(anonymous)],
    //             qr
    //     :
    //         [Function(anonymous)],
    //             message
    //     :
    //         [AsyncFunction(anonymous)],
    //             message_create
    //     :
    //         [Function(anonymous)],
    //      
    //      ....
    //            
    //
    //     }
    //
    // }

});
```

The `wwjsInstances.getInstance("name1")` in the `.then()` callback works and it returns the `Client` object

I got another `.js` file named `process.js`, it is a `.js` file I run with `node ./app/queues/process.js` to run & process my jobs.
I am using `node.js` `OptimalBits/bull` queue

This is my `process.js` file:

```
const EventEmitter = require("events");
EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 50;

// The processor to define/link [ Job Processing Function ]
const processorModule = require("../tasks/File/processor");

// The producer [ Queue ]
const { uploadFileByIdQueue, sendWhatsAppMessageQueue  } = require(".");

const wwjsServiceModule = require("../services/wwjsService");
const wwjsInstances = require('../../app/services/wwjsInstances');


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Handler : Failure
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
const handleFailure = (job, err) => {
    if (job.attemptsMade >= job.opts.attempts) {

        console.log(`Job failures above threshold in ${job.queue.name} for: ${JSON.stringify(
            job.data
        )}`);

        job.remove();
        return null;
    }

    console.log(`Job in ${job.queue.name} failed for: ${JSON.stringify(job.data)} with ${
        err.message
    }. ${job.opts.attempts - job.attemptsMade} attempts left`);

};


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Handler : Completed
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
const handleCompleted = job => {

    console.log(`Job in ${job.queue.name} completed for: ${JSON.stringify(job.data)}`);

    job.remove();

};


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Handler : Stalled
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
const handleStalled = job => {

    console.log(`Job in ${job.queue.name} stalled for: ${JSON.stringify(job.data)}`);

};



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Queue(s) > Active
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
const activeQueues = [
    // {
    //     queue: uploadFileByIdQueue, // Queue
    //     processor: processorModule.uploadFileByIdProcessor // Processor
    // },
    {
        queue: sendWhatsAppMessageQueue, // Queue
        processor: processorModule.sendWhatsAppProcessor // Processor
    }
];



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Queue(s) > For Each > Loop
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
activeQueues.forEach(handler => {

    console.log('[WhatsApp] : process.js > activeQueues.forEach() > wwjsInstances > Singleton: ', wwjsInstances);
    // [WRONG, NOT UPDATED] > Result: wwjsInstances { message: 'I am an instance', instances: {} }

    let client = wwjsInstances.getInstance("foodcrush")

    console.log('[WhatsApp] : process.js > activeQueues.forEach() > wwjsInstances.getInstance("foodcrush"):', client);
    // [WRONG, NOT UPDATED] > Result: undefined


    // Get > Queue
    const queue = handler.queue;

    // Get > Processor
    const processor = handler.processor;

    const failHandler = handler.failHandler || handleFailure;
    const completedHandler = handler.completedHandler || handleCompleted;

    // here are samples of listener events : "failed","completed","stalled", the other events will be ignored
    queue.on("failed", failHandler);
    queue.on("completed", completedHandler);
    queue.on("stalled", handleStalled);

    queue.process(processor);// link the correspondant processor/worker

    console.log(`Queue > getJobs: ${JSON.stringify(queue.getJobs(), null, 2)}...`);
    console.log(`Processing ${queue.name}...`);

});
```

As you can see with the `process.js` I ran with `node ./app/queues/process.js`, the `Singleton` class object value (`instance`) is never updated,

it still shows the old default value defined in the `.js` class file

`wwjsInstances` returns `{ message: 'I am an instance', instances: {} }`
and
`wwjsInstances.getInstance("foodcrush")` returns `undefined`

the update to the `instance` class object value done in `/server.js` never persisted, why is that?

Comment: Are you sure `setInstance()` is being called before you're logging `wwjsInstances`? The `wwjsInstances` class doesn't look like it has a `setInstance` method, maybe your code is crashing because you're calling a method that doesn't exist? `_instances = [];` is probably better declared as an object `_instances = {};` if you're going to be adding non numeric keys to it. NodeJS should be able to log those non-numeric keys of the array, so I don't think that would be your issue though.

Comment: hi, sorry its just a typo, I have updated the `singleton` class, its still the same, `wwjsInstances { message: 'I am an instance', instances: {} }` any changes in `index.js` was never transfered to `text.js` even with the `require(...)`, is the changes even supposed to persist?

Comment: Yes the changes should persist. If you add a log to `setInstance()` do you see that appear log before your log in the test.js file?

Comment: I set the `instances` inside `index.js` file, and imported it into `text.js` both file have no connection/relationship at all

Comment: Yeah, even though both files may not be related they're both using the same singleton instance, which is represented by the same reference throughout your entire app, so modifying it in `index.js` should mean that change is visible in `test.js`. The only thing that I can think of is that `.setInstance()` is being called after and not before you're trying to log it with `console.log('wwjsInstances: ', wwjsInstances);` inside of `test.js` (that's why I was wondering about what occurs if you add a log to `setInstance` so that you can check what order things are executing)

Comment: `test.js` is actually a `queue` (`optimalbits/bull`), I run it like `node ./app/queues/process/test.js`, I checked the `singleton` in a `nodejs` `controller.js` file and it shows the updated property values. but in the `queue` file I started with `node ./app/queues/process/test.js`, it is showing the default values, why is the singleton state not in sync

Comment: You know how to [edit]. I recommend to use that to add more info.

Comment: I guess one issue is that your single instance gets recreated every time you import it. You should update the constructor to flag once that instance has been created and then reuse that instance: [Simplest/cleanest way to implement a singleton in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646297)

Comment: Also, I assume that when you run `node ./app/queues/process.js` something also starts the sever.js file. Otherwise, you have two separate independent programs (one for server.js running and another for process.js) which both have their own memory, so they would each have their own singleton instance.